# Controlling the spacing between grouped bars in Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to add some space between bars. Here is an example of the bar chart that I want to modify,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Alex', 'Alex', 'Sofia', 'Sofia'], 'Age': [15, 18, 16, 22], 'Gender': ['M', 'F', 'M', 'F']})

age_plot = sns.barplot(data=df, x="Age", y="Name", hue="Gender")
plt.show()
```

[image: Here is the output]

I want to add some space between the M and F bars. Right now they are completely attached. I have searched and searched but haven't found a good solution. There was one solution that suggested to add an empty category but that does not work for my dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1. Using `set_width` for each patch

One way would be to use `set_width` over each of the patches in the plot. This can be quite powerful for cases where you want each bar width to represent maybe another quantity.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Alex', 'Alex', 'Sofia', 'Sofia'], 
                   'Age': [15, 18, 16, 22], 
                   'Gender': ['M', 'F', 'M', 'F']})

age_plot = sns.barplot(data=df, x="Age", y="Name", hue="Gender")

for i in age_plot.patches:
  i.set_height(0.3)

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

#### Using `edgecolor` and `linewidth`

Another way to do this is via using `linewidth` and `edgecolor` parameters. You can make a broad edge using linewidth and then color it as white -

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Alex', 'Alex', 'Sofia', 'Sofia'], 
                   'Age': [15, 18, 16, 22], 
                   'Gender': ['M', 'F', 'M', 'F']})

age_plot = sns.barplot(data=df, x="Age", y="Name", hue="Gender", linewidth=5, edgecolor='w')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You might also want to subtract half the difference between the current height and `0.3`, from the bar's y position. That way, the tick labels would stay nicely centered.